# sed - apply substitution between patterns

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I have two patterns `START` and `END` and want to substitute every space with an underscore between these patterns.

Example

```
Lorem ipsum dolor START sit amet, consectetur END adipiscing elit.
```

should be transformed to

```
Lorem ipsum dolor START_sit_amet,_consectetur_END adipiscing elit.
```

I know the regex for replace every space with an underscore

```
sed 's/ /_/g'
```

And I also know how to match the part between the two patterns

```
sed 's/.*START\(.*\)END.*/\1/g'
```

But I have no idea how to combine these two things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative you may use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(START.*?END)/$1=~s#\s#_#gr/ge'
```

The `(START.*?END)` pattern matches a substring between `START` and `END` while capturing it into Group 1 and then `s#\s#_#gr` replaces each single whitespace (`\s`) with `_` in the contents of the group.

Or, if you are using Perl that does not support the `r` option:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:START|\G(?!^))(?:(?!END).)*?\K\s/_/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VHbqna) and the [second regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/kwQdmA/1).

The `(?:START|\G(?!^))(?:(?!END).)*?\K\s` matches

- `(?:START|\G(?!^))` - `START` substring or the end of the previous successful match (with `\G(?!^)`)
- `(?:(?!END).)*?` - any char but a line break char, not starting the `END` substring, as few as possible
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding the previously matched text
- `\s` - a whitespace char.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` to do your job:

```
awk -v ts='START ' -v te='END ' '{
   while (n = index($0, ts)) {
      m = index($0, te)
      if (m > n) {
         s = substr($0, n, m-n)
         gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "_", s)
         $0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) s substr($0, m)
      }
   }
} 1' file
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor START_sit_amet,_consectetur_END adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='(START|END)' 'RT=="END"{gsub(" ","_")}{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file
```

This relies on the record separator `RS` set to either `START` or `END`.

If the `END` tag is reached, the record is updated to replace spaces with underscores using the function `gsub()`.

The last statement prints the whole record including the record terminator `RT` (matched with `RS`).

Note that this solution allows to have `START` and `END` across different lines (and necessary on the same line).

Comment: @DOWNVOTER: Please explain WHY?